# How to link html pages in 2 different drives in same computer?

Tags: html

Can we link html pages in 2 different folders located in different drives (Say one in Drive:C and another in Drive:E) in same computer?

I can go up multiple directories and to different folders or subfolders using internal links, but am not able to navigate to another drive, max can go up to root directory in same drive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but why do you need that?

What language do you use for your server?

Comment: I am learning JavaScript with HTML & CSS. So it is more of an academic need. Will be helpful to know how to link an HTML page in another drive using internal links.

Comment: You will need to create your own server, like nodejs server then tell them to serve the file in your own way. If just only html/css/js this is impossible, bc they are client language.

Comment: My apologies, looks like my query is not clear. I will revert to this later once I have gone through more material on the subject and if necessary rephrase my question, if it is still valid then. Thanks for your help.